# POST Json to PHP get VAR

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, json

i have a form like this:

```
 <?php 
    include '../db/baza.php';
    ?>
    <?php include 'vrh.php' ?> 
        <div id="stranica">
            <div id="stranicaOkvir">
                <form action="dodaj_sliku_obrada.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload" class="upload">

                <fieldset>
                <legend>Dodaj sliku</legend>

                   <?php $upit = "SELECT kategorija_ID, kategorija_naziv FROM kategorije ORDER BY kategorija_ID ASC";
                     $ispis = mysql_query($upit) or die(mysql_error());
                     $blok_ispis = mysql_fetch_assoc($ispis);
                     $ukupno = mysql_num_rows($ispis);   ?> 
                     <p><strong>Obavezno odaberite kategoriju kojoj slika pripada</strong></p>
                            <p> <select name="kategorija" id="kategorija">
                                <?php do { ?>  
                    <option value="<?php echo $blok_ispis['kategorija_ID']; ?>"> <?php echo $blok_ispis['kategorija_naziv']; ?></option>
                    <?php } while ($blok_ispis = mysql_fetch_assoc($ispis)); ?>
                    <?php mysql_free_result($ispis);?>
                </select>   
                </p>

                <input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" required multiple> 
                <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Dodaj sliku"> 
                <div class="progresbar">
                    <span class="progresbar-puni" id="pb"><span class="progresbar-puni-tekst" id="pt"></span></span>
                </div>
                <div id="uploads" class="uploads">
                    Uploaded file  links will apper here.
                <script src="js/dodaj_Sliku.js"></script>
                <script>
                document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click',function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var f = document.getElementById('file'),
                        pb = document.getElementById('pb'),
                        pt = document.getElementById('pt');
                    app.uploader({
                        files: f,
                        progressBar: pb,
                        progressText: pt,
                        processor: 'dodaj_sliku_obrada.php',

                        finished: function(data){
                            var uploads = document.getElementById('uploads'),
                            uspjesno_Dodano = document.createElement('div'),
                            neuspjelo_Dodavanje = document.createElement('div'),
                            anchor,
                            span,
                            x;


                            if(data.neuspjelo_Dodavanje.length){
                                neuspjelo_Dodavanje.innerHTML = '<p>Nazalost, sljedece nije dodano: </p>';
                            }
                            uploads.innerText = '';
                            uploads.textContent = '';

                            for( x = 0; x < data.uspjesno_Dodano.length; x = x + 1){
                                anchor = document.createElement('a');
                                anchor.href = '../slike/galerija/' + data.uspjesno_Dodano[x].file;
                                anchor.innerText = data.uspjesno_Dodano[x].name;
                                anchor.textContent = data.uspjesno_Dodano[x].name;
                                anchor.target = '_blank';
                                uspjesno_Dodano.appendChild(anchor);
                            }

                                for( x = 0; x < data.neuspjelo_Dodavanje.length; x = x + 1){
                                span = document.createElement('span');
                                span.innerText = data.neuspjelo_Dodavanje[x].name;
                                span.textContent = data.neuspjelo_Dodavanje[x].name;
                                neuspjelo_Dodavanje.appendChild(span);
                            }

                            uploads.appendChild(uspjesno_Dodano);
                            uploads.appendChild(neuspjelo_Dodavanje);
                        },

                        error: function(){
                            console.log('Ne radi!');
                        }

                    });
                });
                </script>

                <script>

                </script>

                </div>
                </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php include 'dno.php' ?>
```

The .js looks like this

```
    var app = app || {};

(function(o){
    "use strict";
    //Privatne metode
    var ajax, getFormData, setProgress;

    ajax = function(data){
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(), uspjesno_Dodano;

        xmlhttp.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(){
            if(this.readyState === 4){
                if(this.status === 200){
                    uspjesno_Dodano = JSON.parse(this.response);

                    if(typeof o.options.finished === 'function'){
                    o.options.finished(uspjesno_Dodano);
                }
                } else {
                if(typeof o.options.error === 'function'){
                o.options.error();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        xmlhttp.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event){
            var percent;
            if(event.lengthComputable === true){
                percent = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
                setProgress(percent);
            }
        });

        xmlhttp.open('post', o.options.processor);
        xmlhttp.send(data);

    };

    getFormData = function(source){
        var data = new FormData(), i;
        for(i = 0; i < source.length; i = i + 1){
            data.append('file[]', source[i]);
        }
        data.append('ajax', true);
        data.append('kategorija', o.options.kategorija);
        return data;
    };


    setProgress = function(value){
        if(o.options.progressBar !== undefined){
            o.options.progressBar.style.width = value ? value + '%' : 0;
        }

        if(o.options.progressText !== undefined){
            o.options.progressText.innerText = value ? value + '%' : '';
            o.options.progressText.textContent = value ? value + '%' : '';
        }
    };

    o.uploader = function(options){
        o.options = options;
        if(o.options.files !== undefined){
            ajax(getFormData(o.options.files.files));
        }
    }

}(app));
```

On the process.php part i want to listen the option value from select

```
"<select name="kategorija" id="kategorija">"
```

on the process.php when i

```
  <?php 
        $kategorija = $_POST['kategorija'];
    echo echo $kategorija;
    ?>
```

i alwasy get a 0 value, so what i am doing wrong? The file[] processing is working fine, but can't get it to work with a addtional variable.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `echo echo $kategorija;` It should be `echo $kategorija;` If this causes an issue, which it might, try `var_dump($kategorija)` to view the contents of the variable.

Also, you're including your js throughout the page, this should be refactored and included properly in the head. The php should not be in the form of the document, it should be contained outside and included like you are doing with '../db/baza.php'; Finally, look into using PDO to connect to your db.

Comment: Still the same the second echo was a write mistake. on echo $kategorija; and var_dump still nothing to show. I think in the script tag on the form page i should write additional code, which would send the variable via json to the process.php but don't know what. I know the code is a lill messy, but the question is to make it to work.